# For each scalar `T`, is there any guarantee an integer of the same size exists?

Tags: c++, c, integer, scalar

If `T` is a scalar type, and `N = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)`, is `uintN_t` guaranteed to exist?  If no, is it true in most cases, but with a few exceptional case types?  ( `long double`, and member function pointers come to mind. )

**For reference**:

- `intN_t`, `uintN_t`

  - N1548 §7.20.1.1 ¶3: "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names."
- `scalar types`

  - N3242 §3.9 ¶9: "Arithmetic types, enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types, **std::nullptr_t**, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called *scalar types*."

Comment: I cannot really figure out what the question is. What is *scalar* to you?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Then read the C standard.

Comment: Why would you think such a thing would exist?  There is a `inttypes.h` (C99) and `cinttypes` (C++ equivalent) which contain similar definitions but those standards only guarantee up to uint64_t.  And what does "most cases" mean?  64=2^6 and on a 32-bit system I guess maybe in theory you could have 2^32 size integer therefore NO, it is false in most cases.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas N3242 §3.9 ¶9:  "Arithmetic types, enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types, std::nullptr_t, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called scalar types."

Comment: **The answer is no**. I have built a conformant C implementation that uses 1024-bit ints, and the Standard doesn't specify the `uint1024_t` type. I would post the entire implementation right here, but it doesn't fit in this comment field...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types `uintX_t` are optional, so there is no guarantee that there will be any at all in your implementation. <strike>Other than that, there is no precise definition of what *scalar* means to you.</strike>

Comment: "Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types" (C99 6.2.5.21)

Comment: N1548 §7.20.1.1 ¶3:  "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with
widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a
two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names."

Comment: N3242 §3.9 ¶9:  "Arithmetic types, enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types, std::nullptr_-t, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called scalar types."

Comment: @CharlesLWilcox: At any rate the answer stands, at least in C++, all of those types are *optional*, so you cannot really depend on their existence.

Answer (score 1):

Many processors and/or compilers implement `long double` types larger than any integer type, regardless of name, and there are processors with *32* byte pointers.

So, no.